# Does the simpleGrid require additional downloads?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I want to try the [simpleGrid](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html) in a HotTowel project. When it came to:

```
this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: this.items, ....
```

it threw an exception:

> Unable to get property 'viewModel' of undefined or null reference`

I stepped through and found that ko.simpleGrid is undefined.

Must any other files be added or is simpleGrid available from the standard Knockout.js library?

Comment: Simplegird is not built in. You need to download and include it: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/knockout.simpleGrid.1.3.js

Comment: nevesv's link is old ... better to go to the [Knockout grid example page](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html), click the jsFiddle link at the bottom, then in the jsFiddle expand the External Resources in the left nav. There should be a link to the simpleGrid js file. As of October 2017 it is knockout.simpleGrid.3.0.js.  Incidentally, I also think it's a big omission that this wasn't mentioned on their example page.

Answer (score 8):

Check the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QSRBR/) provides in the Simple Grid sample. It need the KO library + knockout.simpleGrid.1.3.js

And you need to define the PageGridModel

```
ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(initialData));
```